# Deactivate Wlan Adapter via Powershell

Tags: wireless-networking, script, powershell

I want to deactivate and then activate my wlan adapter via powershell. I already queried the Hardware-ID of the device. My script looks like this:

```
$wireless = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter | where {$_.DeviceId -eq 12}
$wireless.Disable()
Start-Sleep -s 1
$wireless.Enable()
read-host
```

But when I run the script it throws no error. But the wlan-connection keeps established.
I'm pretty sure it's the right hardware-ID (I only have one device from Intel, and that's my wireless lan device).

I already googled the problem, but couldn't solve it :-/
Happy for any help!
Thanks!
Tobi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some situations like this i recommend don't reinvent the wheel. Windows has for years the command netsh, you could use for this task:

Disable the adapter:

```
netsh interface set interface "The Name of your Wireless Adapter" Disabled
```

Enable the adapter:

```
netsh interface set interface "The Name of your Wireless Adapter" Enable
```

don't forget to run them as admin

Comment: I had to enter the line "netsh interface set interface name = "NameOfMyInterface" admin=enable. When no authenticated as an admin, netsh will return that the requested interface doesn't exist insted of an errormessage like "no permission". Tanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that the PowerShell scripts does not have Administrator access.

For more info see also [Windows Network adaptor disable enable via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053659/windows-network-adaptor-disable-enable-via-powershell).